# Cannot erase a shared_ptr from set

Tags: c++, set, shared-ptr

I am trying to have an object with a set of pointers to another object. when I try to erase on of the set's values I get an error and crash, I really dont know what could be causing it. here is the library and after that the main function:
when I try to run it it does everything its supposed to do, and when it gets to the removeemployee it crashes and sends out the following: Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

I run it on clion if that matters, and in c++11.

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Manager.h"

Manager::Manager(int id, string firstName, string lastName, int birthYear)
        : Citizen(id, firstName, lastName,birthYear), salary(0), employees(), work_flag(false) {}

int Manager::getSalary() const {
    return salary;
}

void Manager::setSalary(int _salary) {
    if((salary + _salary) < 0){
        salary = 0;
    }else {
        salary += _salary;
    }
}

void Manager::addEmployee(Employee* employee_add) {
    shared_ptr<Employee> employee(employee_add);
    if(employees.find(employee) != employees.end()){
        throw mtm::EmployeeAlreadyExists();
    }
    employees.emplace(employee);
}

//this is the function

void Manager::removeEmployee(int id) {
    for(auto it = employees.begin(); it != employees.end(); it++){
        if(it->get()->getId() == id){
            employees.erase(it);
            return;
        }
    }
    throw mtm::EmployeeDoesNotExists();
}

Manager *Manager::clone() {
    return new Manager(*this);
}

ostream &Manager::printShort(ostream &os) const {
    os<<this->getFirstName()<<" "<<this->getLastName()<<endl;
    os<<"Salary :"<<this->getSalary()<<endl;
    return os;
}

ostream &Manager::printLong(ostream &os) const {
    os<<this->getFirstName()<<" "<<this->getLastName()<<endl;
    os<<"id - "<<this->getId()<<" birth_year - "<<this->getBirthYear()<<endl;
    os<<"Salary :"<<this->getSalary()<<endl;
    os<<"Employees:"<<endl;
    for(const auto & employee : employees){
        employee->printShort(os);
    }
    return os;
}

bool Manager::findEmployee(int id) {
    int i = 0;
    for(const auto & employee : employees){
        cout<<++i<<endl;
        if(employee->getId() == id){
            cout<<"return true"<<endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    cout<<"return false"<<endl;
    return false;
}

bool Manager::isWorkFlag() const {
    return work_flag;
}

void Manager::setWorkFlag(bool workFlag) {
    work_flag = workFlag;
}
```

and this is the main function:

```
int main() {
    Employee e1(1, "John", "Williams", 2002);
    Employee e2(2, "Alex", "Martinez", 2000);
    Manager m1(1,"Robert", "stark", 1980);
    m1.addEmployee(&e1);
    m1.addEmployee(&e2);
    Employee e3(7, "Reuven", "Guetta", 2001);
    m1.addEmployee(&e3);
    m1.printLong(cout);
    cout<<"Delete"<<endl;
    //here is the problem
    m1.removeEmployee(e2.getId());
    m1.printLong(cout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void Manager::addEmployee(Employee* employee_add)` has an error-prone parameter type `Employee*`, because this type does not communicate that the function is _taking ownership_ of the memory pointed to.  You bug is that you are able to pass a pointer to memory that is already owned by something else - in your case, the function scope.

Comment: it workes well when I remove the     m1.removeEmployee(e2.getId());
line... but I would like to know what bug is that, to prevent it from happening

Comment: Change `void Manager::addEmployee(Employee* employee_add)` to `void Manager::addEmployee(shared_ptr<Employee> employee_add)`.  That will convey to the calling code that the Manager will be sharing ownership of the object, and that the calling code must provide a shared_ptr in the first place.  (Sam's answer is better, but just showing how you'd want to do it if you had a good reason to have shared ownership.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
shared_ptr<Employee> employee(employee_add);
```

There is only one reason to have a `shared_ptr`, in the first place; there's only one reason for its existence; it has only one mission in its life, as explained in every C++ textbook: to be able to `new` an object, and have the `shared_ptr` automatically take care of `delete`ing it when all references to the object are gone, avoiding a memory leak.

In your program this object was not instantiated in dynamic scope with `new`:

```
    Employee e2(2, "Alex", "Martinez", 2000);
    Manager m1(1,"Robert", "stark", 1980);
    m1.addEmployee(&e1);

    // etc, etc, etc...
```

and that's the reason for the crash.

If you are not using `new`, simply get rid of all `shared_ptr`s in the shown code.

Comment: Ohhhhh, so I should just use set<Employee *> instead?

Comment: Yes, but it will also be your responsibility to keep the objects these pointers are pointing to as long as they're still being used, in some form or fashion. In the shown code they're all declared in `main()`, and therefore they will be automatically destroyed when `main` returns, so you need to make sure there isn't any destructor, somewhere, in global scope that then ends up getting invoked, and poke its nose into one of these sets. It would discover pointers to deleted objects. Hillarity will ensue.

Comment: Minor niggle: To me, the described is the mission for `unique_ptr`. `shared_ptr` adds a requirement for multiple simultaneous owners to the mission. `shared_ptr`'s the right smart pointer for this job because an employee having (is owned by) multiple managers is something all-too-possible in a corporate structure. Otherwise `employees` might as well directly contain the `Employee`.